# Disabling Excel Warning Message about Active Content

Tags: excel

I am dynamically creating Hyperlinks in an excel spreadsheet linking to a set of html pages also located on the same PC. The html pages load java script files. When clicking on the URL then the correct HTML page opens in the browser but as a side product I am also getting the following warning message:

[image: Warning Message about Active Content]

My question is how to stop the information window popping up after clicking on the hyperlink in Excel. I looked at internet options and also at the Trust Center within Excel but was not able to successfully remove the information window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options to solve this without messing with security options.

1. Use the UNC path
2. change the link to call the file via a local webserver (e.g., IIS or Apache) on localhost